# JS getAttribute & settAttribute for multiple items

Tags: javascript, html

How to use getAttribute & setAttribute on a list of multiple items for the below nav menu list?

```
const navBar = document.getElementById('navbar__list')

for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   let text = "Section " + i;
   let li = document.createElement('li');
   let link = document.createElement('a');
   let newText = document.createTextNode(text);

   link.appendChild(newText);
   li.appendChild(link);
   navBar.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? What do you want to achieve specifically?

Comment: i created 4 nav menu li dynamically using javascript, then i want to link the li items with their corresponding text in the page with href attribute, is there a way to do it for all the sections at once ?

Comment: I don't see how you would do it at once as each anchor should have a specific href, or what you're trying to achieve here, please?

Comment: What are the links?

Comment: `const dataAttribute1 = link.getAttribute('Section 1');
    const dataAttribute2 = link.getAttribute('Section 2');
    const dataAttribute3 = link.getAttribute('Section 3');
    const dataAttribute4 = link.getAttribute('Section 4');
    const setAttribute1 = link.setAttribute('href', '#section1');
    const setAttribute2 = link.setAttribute('href', '#section2');
    const setAttribute3 = link.setAttribute('href', '#section3');
    const setAttribute4 = link.setAttribute('href', '#section4');`

Comment: @MennaRihan I wrote an answer which is working for you 100%, let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use `link.href` to access and modify the `href` of your `link` anchor tag. Assuming your navbar urls have some sort of pattern related to `i`, one possibility is to use:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   let text = "Section " + i;
   let li = document.createElement('li');

   let link = document.createElement('a');
   //set link, e.g.
   link.href = "#section_" + i
   
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Menna Rihan

This implementation will work just fine:

```
const navBar = document.getElementById('navbar__list')

for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   let text = "Section " + i;
   let li = document.createElement('li');
   let link = document.createElement('a');
   let newText = document.createTextNode(text);
    
   link.setAttribute('href', '#' + text.toLowerCase().replace(' ', ''));
   link.textContent = text;

   li.appendChild(link);
   navBar.appendChild(li);
}
```